# Exporting a class from a dll that inherits from a template

Tags: c++, templates, dll, linker-errors

I am exporting a class from a dll which inherits from a template base class.  The template base class is not exported from the dll but instead is designed such that it links at compile time like a static library.  The situation is as such:

The base class is defined as such:

```
template<typename _type>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static void CreateSingleton(void);
    static _type* GetSingleton(void);
    static void DestroySingleton(void);

    virtual ~Singleton(void);
protected:
    Singleton(void);
    Singleton(const Singleton<_type> &copyfrom);

    _type* m_ptrSingleton;
};
```

I have a class which inherits from this which is defined as such:

```
#if defined(_ENGINE_EXPORT)
    #define ENGINELINKAGE __declspec(dllexport)
#elif defined(_ENGINE_IMPORT)
    #define ENGINELINKAGE __declspec(dllimport)
#else
    #define ENGINELINKAGE
#endif

class ENGINELINKAGE IWindowManager: public Singleton<IWindowManager>
{
public:
    virtual ~IWindowManager(void) =0;
};
```

I am able to compile but when trying to use IWindowManager in another project that imports from the dll that contains both IWindowManager and Singleton the linker produces the following errors:

```
2>Engine_win32.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class IWindowManager * __cdecl Singleton<class IWindowManager>::GetSingleton(void)" (__imp_?GetSingleton@?$Singleton@VIWindowManager@@@@SAPAVIWindowManager@@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class WindowManager_win32 * __cdecl WindowManager_win32::GetSingleton(void)" (?GetSingleton@WindowManager_win32@@SAPAV1@XZ)
2>WindowManager_win32.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class IWindowManager * __cdecl Singleton<class IWindowManager>::GetSingleton(void)" (__imp_?GetSingleton@?$Singleton@VIWindowManager@@@@SAPAVIWindowManager@@XZ)
2>Window_win32.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class IWindowManager * __cdecl Singleton<class IWindowManager>::GetSingleton(void)" (__imp_?GetSingleton@?$Singleton@VIWindowManager@@@@SAPAVIWindowManager@@XZ)
2>Engine_win32.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl Singleton<class IWindowManager>::DestroySingleton(void)" (__imp_?DestroySingleton@?$Singleton@VIWindowManager@@@@SAXXZ) referenced in function _main
2>Engine_win32.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static class IWindowManager * Singleton<class IWindowManager>::m_ptrSingleton" (?m_ptrSingleton@?$Singleton@VIWindowManager@@@@1PAVIWindowManager@@A)
```

I have defined the classes such that IWindowManager should be exported from the dll but Singleton should not be but rather is staticly linked into the program at compile time.  The reason for this being that if you want to export a template from a dll and you dont have a very specific set of template instances you want available you must staticly link it.  It is not possible to dynamically link the template, but instead you must dynamicly link each instance you are looking to export/import.

The linker errors seem to indicate that it is trying to export Singleton even though I do not specify that it should be exported.

Does anyone understand why this is happening or how I can fix this?

Comment: Is the "Singleton" source include in both the main.cpp and the dll-code.cpp?

Comment: Yes.  The body of each of the functions is in the Singleton.h header.  I left the implementations out in order to reduce the size of the post.

Comment: Ah, but how does the compiler know that you actually want an implementation in the .exe - it won't produce the code for the singleton. Templates rely on the compiler building the template code at compile time... I suspect you can't do this...

Comment: So even though I don't have the Singleton class exported it still wont generate the code at compile time for the project that is using the dll?

Comment: That is how I understand it, doing a dummy-instantioation (e.g. `void dummy() { IWindowManger *mgr = new IWindowManger; ... }`, as ogni42 says would work. However, that will mean that the `Singleton` class is instantiated in the DLL, not in the main exe file.

Comment: Is it possible that rather than dummy instantiating the template that I could instead explicitly instantiate it with the syntax:            
ENGINEEXTERN template class ENGINELINKAGE Singleton<IWindowManager>;

Comment: I think this is supported as a suggestion in the C++ language, but support for it is not implemented in (any/most) compilers. In other words, syntactically it will work, but practically, it won't.

Comment: It turns out also that the design for my singleton doesn't work.  I was able to get around the issue by explicitly instantiating the template but because the thing that is inheriting from Singleton is an abstract class the code that it generates does not compile.  But explicit instantiation does solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class is in the DLL you would have to provide some dummy instantiation in the DLL. Otherwise, no code will be generated for the singleton class. Hence, later compilations will fail, as the IWindowManager class will not be in the lib/DLL.

Sidemark: You should rethink if you *really* need a singleton